# How do I safely allow unprivileged users to copy files to my server?

Tags: linux, security, rsync, file-sharing, chroot

I know that I can use `rsync` over ssh to send files from one Linux computer to another. However, in this case I need to give access to my system to users with a lower level of trust (people who may decide to start snooping in my files in addition to uploading their own). I can make a "submissions" user on my system and give submitters the password so they can use `rsync` over ssh, but then any world-readable file on my system is fair game. I need something like ftp with a chroot jail to keep eyes off my data, but ftp itself is insecure. Am I barking up the wrong tree with `rsync` over ssh when I should really be investigating network shares or something like that?

Goals:

- Users can upload any file of any size and resume the transfer if it is interrupted.
- Users can't see my (or, for bonus points, other unprivileged users') files on the system.

Comment: Does the upload-user need to see the files he uploaded himself?

Comment: user1039462: No, the users don't technically need to see their own files, but I'm not sure how that would work while preserving the ability to resume broken transfers.

Comment: You are right. I wanted to suggest, that you just remove the read privileges for the uploading group, but that doesn't work if you want to resume rsync transfers

Answer (score 4):

You would have a much easier time setting up a SAMBA share.  (http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html)

The security protocols it supports are far more fine tuned and allows for setting up users and the lot. You can also set up groups to place users in if they are already preexisting. I would suggest it as a much better way forward than creating/restricting user accounts.

This would allow you to also entirely restrict them to their folder with no way out and it supports ftp (much more friendly).